# How to place a text to the right

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'd like to place the text "även uppfinnare" to the right like in this mockup:
[image]

I can display everything except the text farthest to the right when this is the actual result with dynamic data:
[image]

The HTML and JSP that does this is:

```
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="fl10"><h3>Sökande</h3></div>
        <% if(apc.hasSokande()) {
        if(sokandeList != null && sokandeList.size() > 0) { %>
        <% for(PersonInfo person : sokandeList) { %>
        <div class="data-box">
            <table border="0">
    <tr><td colspan=3><strong>  <% if (person.getNamn() != null) { %>
                <%= person.getNamn() %>&nbsp;
            <% } %> </strong></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>Telefon</td><td><%= person.getTelefon() %></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>Fax</td><td><%= person.getFax() %></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>E-post</td><td><%= person.getEpost() %></td></tr>
        <tr><td><%= person.getLandKod() %></td><td>Referens</td><td></td></tr>
        </table>    
    </div>  
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="fl10"></div>


        <% } %>
    <% } %>
    <% } else { %>
        <%= apc.getNyregPerson().getNamn() %>
    <% } %>

        </div>
```

Can you please tell me how I can achieve the text on the right? I tried with a div and float:right but it didn't work. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `HTML` `div` tag would be more suitable for such design. Create two divs for columns.

```
    <div id="personName">
      ......
   </div>
    <div id="otherDetails">
       .....
   </div>
   <br style="clear:both;"/>
```

CSS:

```
  #personName {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    background:#9c9;
 }
 #otherDetails {
    float:right;
    width:450px;
    background:#c9c;
 }
```

Check : [example](http://cssdesk.com/d64uy)

Answer (score 2):

You can use absolute positioning like this one.

```
<span style='position:absolute; top:10px; right:0px;'>även uppfinnare</span>
```